Tiny MCE Editor Loads
When the Tiny team mentions "editor loads" in their pricing, do they mean the number of times a page is loaded that includes the  tag, or is it every time I call $(element).fancybox() in my code?
Thanks in advance for taking the time to answer!
Regards,
Jonathan Atkinson

Customer service questions, including billing and licence issues, are off topic here. See [help/on-topic] point #4
